# How to add list, dropdown and textbox controls dynamically in asp.net infragestic web data grid columns

Tags: asp.net

Please share solution or code if any available

I have data in data table.  On the initial page load how do I add controls like dropdown, list, edit grid cell option and search controls in grid view columns dynamically along with data using asp.net  c# code?

The grid I am using:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <igGridControls:WebDataGrid
            ID="grdMain"
            EnableViewState="true"
            runat="server"
            Height="100px"
            AutoGenerateColumns="true"
        >
        </igGridControls:WebDataGrid>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please provide the solution code